# Copying & Renaming Files with GNU Parallel

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have a simple script that I want to copy and rename files, in `files.lst` based on a list of names in `names.lst`

```
**name.lst**
100GV200.vcf
150GV200.vcf
14300GV200.vcf

**file.lst**
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

My script so far looks like this:

```
parallel --link -k "cp {} {}" :::: file.lst :::: name.lst
```

Unfortunately I get back:

```
 cp: target `100GV200.vcf` is not a directory
```

When I run a single `cp` command in the terminal it works perfectly

```
cp file1.txt 100GV200.vcf
```

Where am I going wrong in understanding how GNU parallel reads in arguments?

Comment: Always try `--dry-run` if you do not understand what GNU Parallel is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use {1} and {2} notation:

```
parallel --link -k cp {1} {2} :::: file.lst :::: name.lst
```

Works for me, it will work with the quotes as well

```
parallel --link -k "cp {1} {2}" :::: file.lst :::: name.lst
```

To get it to work with {}, you would have had to do something like this:

```
parallel --link -k "cp {}" :::: file.lst :::: name.lst
```

Because parallel will automatically append the line of the two files.

Comment: Works perfectly. Why does {1} and {2} work but just empty {} not? I thought it would pull 1 argument from file.lst and the other from name.lst

Comment: If you don't specify which input is suppose to be used for the copy, parallel append, for example, if you remove the file 100GV200.vcf and you do this: mv file1.txt 100GV200.vcf file1.txt 100GV200.vcf, you will get the error you were getting.  By telling parallel what line you want to go where, you get the move command as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with parallel's deranged interface; for file names without special characters you can just go for

```
paste file.lst name.lst | xargs -n2 echo mv
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used below command to achieve the same

```
paste file.lst name.lst|  awk '{print "cp" " " $1 " " $2}'|sh
```